# css background-image specific to Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, background-image

Is it possible to set the CSS `background-image` (or even just `background`) specific to Firefox? I tried specifying `-moz-background-image`:

```
.myClass
{ 
   background-image: url(../images/1.svg);
   -moz-background-image: url(../images/1.png); } 
}
```

but Firebug reveals:

> Unknown property 'moz-background-image'. Declaration dropped.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Firefox has no problem supporting SVG background images.

Comment: That's what I thought - but I've got an page with several SVG graphics, and I'm using Jquery Draggable to click-drag the page (similar to Google Maps) and it is almost unusable in Firefox. It locks up almost completely and dragging hardly works. It's only a problem in Firefox. So as a test, I put the PNGs back in (which were originally used) and it works as expected.

Comment: So to fully answer your question, this is more of a temporary band-aid so that I can track down the underlying issue.

Comment: Yes, Ihan16, you are right. But if you need to apply some specific styles, well, there is a way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

    .myClass {
        background-image: url(../images/1.png);
    }

}
```

A little example:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/TSQmj/

But beyond that, as some folks commented, there is no need for this with Firefox (I'll test this):

http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

There is another one for webkit too:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    ...

}
```

Comment: Yep that worked, thanks! I've never seen that `@-moz-document url-prefix()` declaration before, and Visual Studio **hates** the syntax! :)

Comment: I'm glad to make Visual Studio sad, hahaha

Comment: Here is an example of *one* of the SVGs I'm using. Do you think it could be the embedded image (which is just the shadow underneath) could be what's causing the slowdown in FF? http://jsfiddle.net/7VCFH/

Comment: Hummm... on my Firefox (20.0, OSX 10.8.3) it goes just fine. Did you try to archive that result using box-shadow?

Comment: Nope. I'm not actually sure what you mean by that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30090/discussion-between-coma-and-lhan16)